# 'Choose from the most used tags' button shows 'No tags found' instead of showing the most used tags

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

While adding or editing posts in the WordPress backend, I am not able to add(assign) tags to posts. When I click on the 'Choose from the most used tags' button, it shows 'No tags found'. But there are more than a dozen of tags already added to other posts. Adding tags using the textbox is also not working.

This issue is occurring only after I updated WPML plugin. Before updating the plugin, this was working properly. I searched the web but still not able to figure out how to solve this issue.

What do I need to change or configure to get the adding tags functionality working again in combination with the WPML plugin?

Comment: @rene Thanks for the edit. This seems to be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue now. The WPML plugin version which I am using seems to have this issue by default.

To solve this issue, I added the following code outside of WPML plugin(a plugin which I developed).

```
    // Code to fix 'No tags found' issue in admin backend
add_filter('icl_current_language', 'icl_current_language_preview_hack_filter_func',200);
function icl_current_language_preview_hack_filter_func($lang){

    if(isset($_GET['lang'])){
        $lang = esc_html($_GET['lang']);
    }
    elseif(isset($_COOKIE['_icl_current_admin_language']))
    {
        $lang=$_COOKIE['_icl_current_admin_language'];
    }
    else
    {
        $lang="en";
    }
    return $lang;
}
```

**Note** The above code can be added in any of the plugins.

**Explanation** When we try to add tags to a post, WPML plugin tries to fetch the tags for the current selected language. By default, for every operation, WPML stores current language in Cookie and retrieves it whenever needed. But in this case I dont know why WPML fetches the current language from $_GET instead of Cookie and $_GET returns nothing.

So I have tweaked that code by fetching the current language using Cookie if current language is not available in $_GET.

Hope this answer is helpful for some who are having this issue.